# IIS Express slow on external requests using Parallels VM on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, parallels

Running a VM on a Mac for a .NET backend, I have the following setup:

Parallels 8 (Shared Network), Win 8, IIS Express 8 (not run as admin I think), Visual Studio 2012 Epress

ACL via elevated command line:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.211.55.3:29588/ user=everyone
```

applicationhost.config

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49288:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49288:10.211.55.3" />
</bindings>
```

The usual tutorials about this topic use the win8 hostname, which doesn't work in my case. I have to use the direct IP address. The other thing that is unusual here is that I have to leave the localhost in the bindings, otherwise Visual Studio can't start IIS Express (Error).

Above works except that the backend becomes unresponsive after a minute or so. It's like the server goes to sleep. On browser-refresh (Mac side) I get a timeout, then the requests make it through again. On the Win8 side, the backend is repsonsive all the time.

Does somebody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issues with IIS. Local requests are fine, but external requests originating from the Mac host are often slow and sometimes don't work at all. Same behavior on Shared and Bridged network.

Comment: I had a similar issue, except running in Win8 (no VM's). Running a command prompt as administrator and then running IIS Express outside of VS seemed to fix it for me...

Comment: Thanks. What I have done for now is to use Fiddler as a proxy, which allows to use localhost instead of the IP and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this problem is resolved with VS 2012 update 3.